# PHP: Rand array list of words + random numbers

Tags: php

So i want rand array of words such as
Fred, Mark, Peter

Then i need an rand of numbers
152163,312361,6136 etc...

Then combine them together for example:
Peter6136

```
$friends=array("Mike", "Ondrej", "Honza", "Danca", "Misa", "Verca");
array_push($friends, "Michal", "Vendulka", "Daniela");
sort($friends);
$winner = array_rand($friends, 1);
$bgname=time().rand(10,99); $bgrand=rand(1,3);
$bgname5 = $winner + $bgname;
```

This does not provide what i need? Where have i gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's actually a couple of issues with your code.  For one thing, `array_rand` returns the index of the value you should grab, not the value.  So, we simply add `$friend[]` around the index.  Next, you are using the incorrect operator for concatenating strings.  In PHP, you use `.`.  Additionally, I have no idea why you are sorting the array with `sort()` when you are about to pick a random element, seems unnecessary to randomly pick from a sorted list vs an unsorted one.

```
<?php

$friends=array("Mike", "Ondrej", "Honza", "Danca", "Misa", "Verca");
array_push($friends, "Michal", "Vendulka", "Daniela");
//sort($friends);
$winner = $friends[array_rand($friends, 1)];
$bgname=time().rand(10,99);
$bgrand=rand(1,3);
$bgname5 = $winner . $bgname;

echo $bgname5;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate in PHP, you use the `.` operator instead of the `+` operator.

`$bgname5 = $winner . $bgname;`

Comment: It is only outputting numbers such as: 148986335062

Comment: I'm testing with the verbatim code you edited.  It displays a name followed by a very large integer (such as Michal148986421129).  Did you want the number to be between 10 and 99?  If so, `mt_rand(10,99);`